# p-value distribution in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have the genes with their corresponding p-values in the following form:

```
Gene   p-value
gene1  0.01 
gene2  0.02
gene3  0.06
gene4  0.05
gene5  0.09
gene6  0.01
gene7  0.05
gene8  0.09
gene9  0.01
gene10 0.06
```

I would like to create a box-plot as shown in the example below:

[image]

Instead of  months, I would like that to be the number of genes (frequency of genes). According to the huge data set I have, the x-axis should be the number of genes falling under a particular p-value category (which is in the y-axis). So the y-axis will be p-values from say 0.01 to 1.

I used

```
boxplot(gene ~ p-value, col=rainbow(12))
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Couple of things - can you give `str()` of your data? Regardless, you need to refer to the variables properly ie if the `data.frame` is `dat`, `dat$gene`

Comment: str(newmat)
'data.frame': 22810 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ probes : Factor w/ 22810 levels "244901_at","244902_at",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ P.value: num  0.5503 0.4814 0.0145 0.8207 0.5697 ...

Comment: You have a column named `p-value`? That is not a standard name, it confuses with `p - value` (minus).

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft that's why I asked for `str()` - you can see it's actually `P.value`

Comment: I expect `boxplot(probes ~ P.value, data = newmat)` will work. This is a basic error with R syntax, so I'm voting to close. If there's some other problem, let us know

Comment: @alexwhan `boxplot(probes ~ P.value, data = newmat)` will not give the desired output. In fact, I don't think it works at all because `probes` here is a factor.

Comment: @dayne : Yes, it will not work and I tried it already !

Comment: @user1805343 Have you tried the answer I gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the functions `cut` and `aggregate` here. You can learn more about them by running `?cut` and `?aggregate` in your R console. The idea was to take your data frame of genes and p-values and `cut` the p-values into bins. If you want more or less bins you can change the `breaks` argument in the `cut` function. Then you can plot the distribution of p-values by their bin using `boxplot`.

I added the `xaxt=FALSE` argument to `boxplot` so we can define our own custom axis - in this case the number of genes that fall into each bin. I calculated the number of genes by using the `aggregate` function with `length`, then added the axis.

```
set.seed(1)
example <- data.frame(gene=sample(paste("gene",1:10),size=500,replace=TRUE),pval=sample(seq(0.01,1,0.01),500,replace=TRUE))
example$bin <- cut(example$pval,breaks=10)
boxplot(example$pval~example$bin,xaxt="n",ylab="p value",xlab="number of genes")
ngenes <- aggregate(example$gene,by=list("bin"=example$bin),length)
axis(side=1,labels=ngenes$x,at=1:10)
```

[image]

Comment: @user1805343 What do you mean you do not know how to read the data?

Comment: @user1805343 This was meant to show you how to walk through the process with your own data. You should not be modifying my example. Walk through my example to understand what I did, then apply it to your own data. You will take your `newmat` and use the `cut` and `aggregate` functions to make your plot.